# How to remove rows using another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I have my complete dataset, it has 4 columns, but I need to remove all rows that have the customer_id from another dataframe

Here's an example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'client_id' : ['123456', '451245', '563234', '753214', '412456', '442312', '123411', '987654'],
                'name_fran' : [    'will',     'bruce',     'john',     'jorge',     'well',     'dani',     'rafa',     'manoel'],
                'id_fran' : ['331'  ,   '221',   '312',   '531',   '678',   '214',   '456',   '886']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'client_id' : ['123456', '987654']})
```

df1 :

| index | client_id | name_fran | id_fran |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 123456 | will | 331 |
| 1 | 451245 | bruce | 221 |
| 2 | 563234 | john | 312 |
| 3 | 753214 | jorge | 531 |
| 4 | 412456 | well | 678 |
| 5 | 442312 | dani | 214 |
| 6 | 123411 | rafa | 456 |
| 7 | 987654 | manoel | 886 |

df2:

| index | client_id |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 123456 |
| 1 | 987654 |

result I need is this:

| index | client_id | name_fran | id_fran |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 451245 | bruce | 221 |
| 1 | 563234 | john | 312 |
| 2 | 753214 | jorge | 531 |
| 3 | 412456 | well | 678 |
| 4 | 442312 | dani | 214 |
| 5 | 123411 | rafa | 456 |

I've tried a few ways but got no results, what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do `isin`

```
df1 = df1.loc[~df1['client_id'].isin(df2['client_id'])].reset_index(drop=True)
df1
Out[278]: 
  client_id name_fran id_fran
0    451245     bruce     221
1    563234      john     312
2    753214     jorge     531
3    412456      well     678
4    442312      dani     214
5    123411      rafa     456
```

Comment: it worked as well as me! thank you so much!